# Tkinter button not appearing

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

```
root = tk.Tk()


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=2000, width=2000, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg =  "#720E9E")
frame.place(relwidth=0.9, relheight = 0.90, relx = 0.05, rely = 0.05)

findStocks = tk.Button(root, text = "Get Stocks", padx = 10, pady=5, fg = "white", bg = "black", command = getStocks)
findStocks.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

I've tried everything and I'm just not sure why the button widget is not appearing. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I see the button at the bottom when I ran your code. I adjusted hegith and width of the canvas to be smaller thou.

Answer (score 0):

Same as ywbaek. Your code is okay. But you should adjust your canvas height and width. I set it to 400 and 800 respectively and the button showed up in the bottom middle of the canvas.